# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string : C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, base64, password-hash, sha-3

I am new to C# ,Here in my web API project I have some code for hashing the user password using SHA3 .

In API I have 2 methods

First method is used for when new User create an account I just hashing the password and store it in the table.

The second method is for when the same user log In again I fetch the hashed password(string) and verify the current password with it .

Here I have faced the error as I mentioned in the title and I referred some related post in SO also but I could't solve this issue .

I have verified that the stored and fetched string has the same characters also the generated and stored string has the same characters.

I don't know where I did the mistakes .

```
Password  : Abcd@123

 Hashed String : k/OMmdnW6FZ+zsOrE2rkdy8YEUH/rep5dlcRIwnG8Vc7kQ81VL8dEQv2Clyp7iRhb0HSfKtgOLBj5g/YbqHq7FKDj5epafNwasE=
```

Calling Confirm method

```
 bool isPasswordPassed = false;
                if (mHashedPassword != " " && mUserPassword != " ")
                {
                    isPasswordPassed = Hashing.Confirm(mUserPassword, mHashedPassword, Supported_HA.SHA512);
                }
```

Confirm

```
public static bool Confirm(string plainText, string hashValue, Supported_HA hash)
        {
            byte[] hashBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(hashValue);//This line passing the error as in my title.
......
.......
.....
        }
```

But It works fine when I check the code like this ...

```
check(mUserPassword){
    string a = Hashing.ComputeHash(mUserPassword, Supported_HA.SHA512, null);
    bool b = Hashing.Confirm(mUserPassword, a, Supported_HA.SHA512);
}
```

Here I am passing the password to generate hash and the confirm hash but it returns **TRUE**

Can anyone help me to solve this .

Reference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0dgTf9TUDHU

Comment: Down voting with reason is helpful for me in future

Comment: FromBase64String(hashValue) fails so the issue is clearly with the value of hashValue which is *not* the "Hashed String" value you have show as that works fine.

Comment: @AlexK. actually I verified the hashValue the string char is same as stored in DB also I verified the created hash with stored hash. can you help me in this

Comment: Your example hash decodes fine - http://rextester.com/QVIRO42009 - so `hashValue` is not that string, inspect it in the debugger & see what it actually is.

Comment: Debugger shows the same values which I have stored in DB..Really messed with it @AlexK.

Answer (score 0):

It may be an encoding conversion Base64 Unicode.   you should pass the encoding

```
var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(plainText);
string hashValue  = Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
```

then in the Confirm method

```
byte[] hashBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(hashValue);
```

should work. Regards

Comment: Brother after doing this convert it changes the actual values.@PabloDev